# ios: import a pod as framework into aswift ios project without using cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way that I can import a framework that is available as a pod into my swift ios project without using cocoapods?

Comment: Swift package manager? https://swift.org/package-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You should read through the framework's documentation since the specific steps may vary.

Typically you'll just need to

1. **Clone or download** the source/repo

Then from within Xcode:

2. Drag the framework's **.xcodeproj** into your project
3. In the Build Phases Tab, drag the framework's **.framework** into Link Binary with Libraries

Hope this helps someone!